# django login popup

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

I've been trying to figure out how to do a modal login in django and have been having some trouble. Is this possible? It seems like it should be. I imagine the solution involves writing a view that takes a POST request and returns some JSON.

Are there any examples out there of how to do this in a clean way?

Comment: what have you done so far? Where is the trouble? It's certainly possible. Do you want the entire login to take place in the dialog or just present the user with the login form and POST normally.

Comment: I'd like the entire login to happen in the dialog - so post and get json back that says 'success' or something. No page redirection. I'm running into trouble on how to best organize it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found is to do the following:

- Write a simple standalone login view
- Display this view on your pages as an iframe using a javascript modal dialog (I recommend [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)).
- Because you're displaying an iframe, you don't have to worry about ajax sends etc. The iframe can just post data and redirect normally.
- On a successful login, redirect the iframe to a 'success' page. After a few seconds, have that page send a message to the parent window, which can then close the modal box and make any necessary changes to itself.

Comment: Last time I heard iframe cookies will be not shared to parent window so which means the original page is still unauthenticated right?

Comment: I was talking about the session based authentication.